# Multple linear regression, adding one predictor with almost perfect fit make others irrelevant

Tags: regression, linear-model, feature-selection, predictor

I found something interesting while playing with some data and linear regression.

I built a regression with various predictors, more or less correlated with the outcome. Then I added one predictor that is strongly associated with the outcome and suddenly the $R^2$ rose to 80% from less than 10%, which I had achieved after fiddling with the previous predictors. Also all the other predictors became suddenly non significant.

Should I think that the perfect predictor is real and the others are just confounders so I can trash them? Or that this new predictor is a bias?

Comment: In the multiple regression setting the coefficients represent the **independent** contribution made by a predictor in accounting for the outcome. In your case the old predictors are likely redundant in the sense that they don't account for much independent variability, hence they appears as non-significant.

Comment: Were these real data, or simulated data? You can check the multiple $R^2$ of the new predictor variable based on the set of previous predictors (ie, exclude Y).

Comment: @skleene could you elaborate more?

Comment: @gung actually using the new predictor as outcome result in a model with similar adjusted R^2 (even if worse model p value)

Comment: The p value doesn't matter, the point is your new variable is a lot like the set of old variables.

Comment: It sounds like your predictand is very well described by your new predictor. This does not imply your other predictors offer no signal, rather that given your data they offer little value. It is possible they well describe more given your data, but that is a question that is domain specific.